# Setting target to be the NSObject

Tags: ios, uigesturerecognizer, target, nsobject

I have an `NSObject` that creates an `UIImageView`. I add gesture recognizers to the `UIImageView` but the target is not set to the class itself. I would like to know how to do this.

```
//inside the init method of the NSObject:
UITapGestureRecognizer* tapRecognizer = [[UITapGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(handleTap:)];
tapRecognizer.numberOfTapsRequired = 2;
[theImage addGestureRecognizer:tapRecognizer];


//this method is directly beneath the init method of the NSObject, I want this 
//to be called when the image is double tapped
- (void)handleTap:(UITapGestureRecognizer*)recognizer
{

}
```

So what is it I need to set initWithTarget: to? it is not `self` because this crashes the app, yielding a bad access error

Comment: `NSObject` is not a `UIResponder`, so it cannot process `UIEvent`. Just as `UIResponder`'s documents says, "The UIResponder class defines an interface for objects that respond to and handle events"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you set the target in the NSObject class the action will not work. SO you have to add the codes in the ViewController.m class then it will work .